# DigitalOcean SFTP not working on PHPSTORM

Tags: sftp, phpstorm, digital-ocean

I have a droplet on DigitalOcean with SSH key created. 
My SSH and SFTP access work perfectly with Mac OSX Terminal and Transmit.

But for some reason SFTP does not work with PHPSTORM :

```
Error
Connection to 'ipaddress' failed
SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures for root
```

Comment: see [PY-8532](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8532) - does it look similar?

Comment: I have the same issue in Intellij Idea 14 (build: 139.659) - the bug Iena posted seems to be the problem - any solutions for this? Wait for IDEA update?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after a while looking for ssh keys and others non working ideas I was just using a root user which just could not access to server
The error message was buggy, it appear for ssh issues and also user issues :-(